# Connection to valgrind embedded gdb server is failing with an error "Connection reset by peer"

Tags: c++, valgrind, memcheck

I trying to follow the instruction on connecting to valgrind using gdb.
Valgrind memcheck is starts properly and asks to connect using following gdb command:

```
target remote | vgdb --pid=53181
```

but when I run this command, I get an error

> Remote communication error. Target disconnected.: Connection reset by
> peer

what is my mistake?

Comment: Which version of Valgrind? Which platform?

Comment: Valgrind version is 3.13.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Can you try a more recent Valgrind? Current is 3.19 and I expect 3.20 will be released very soon (planned for 22 Oct 2022).

Comment: I tried, it didn't work as well. I suspect it is more likely a gdb 10.2 syntax issue.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so. Valgrind is communicating with vgdb/gdb using named pipes and the protocol seems fairly stable. Does either vgdb or valgrind say anything more useful if you add "-v -v" to them both?

Comment: Just tried adding -v to both valgrind and vgdb. There is no extra messages after I type "target remote | vgdb -v". Valgrind is awaiting on message "(action on error) vgdb me ..." and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that error

> Remote communication error. Target disconnected.: Connection reset by peer.

is general and may indicate invalid command as well. If you run in gdb

```
target remote | something
```

it will give you the same error message.

It appeared for me, that extra space after | symbol was excess.

Correct command was actually

```
target remote |vgdb --pid=53181
```

My GDB version is GNU gdb (Ubuntu 10.2-0ubuntu1~18.04~2) 10.2

Comment: That seems very strange. I have never seen any gdb version needing or not needing a space before/after the | in the target remote command. I have just checked again with GDB 10.2 and it works with or without space. For sure, the above behaviour and answer does not apply generally. I suggest to retest your hypothesis, and if confirm, to give the exact versions of GDB build, the platform, etc ...

Comment: Also, giving: "target remote | something" gives first a message the something is "not found".